# Singular value inequality for sum of 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, singular-values

I found a theorem mentioned in a couple of places, but could not find a proof. 
The theorem states the following:

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{F^{m,n}}$, $p=min(m,n)$ with singular values $\sigma_1(A) \geqslant...\geqslant \sigma_p(A)$ and $\sigma_i(B) \geqslant...\geqslant \sigma_p(B)$ respectively,
then $\sigma_{i+j-1}(A+B) \leqslant \sigma_i(A) + \sigma_j(B)$.

I am looking for a proof of the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{F}^{m,n}$?

Comment: @Vladimir vector space of all $m \times n$ matrices. Basically $A,B$ are both $m \times n$ matrices

Comment: You might wish to consult  I. C. Gohberg and M. G. Krein. Introduction to the Theory of Linear Non-selfadjoint Operators. American Mathematical Society, Providence, R.I.,1969

Comment: These are known as Weyl's inequality for singular value. In many textbooks the proof is given for hermitian case (i.e. for eigenvalues), but the same proof can be extended to singular values as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question (taking cue from the comment of zimbra314).

This can be proved using Courant-Fischer min-max theorem:

> $\sigma_{k+1} = \underset{V \subseteq \mathbb{F}^m,dimV=m-k}{min} \ \ \underset{v \in V,\Vert v \Vert = 1}{max}  \Vert Mv \Vert$, where $M \in \mathbb{F}^{n,m}$ and $\sigma_i$ is the $i$-th singular value in decreasing order.

Using the theorem, we get:

$
\sigma_{i+j+1}(A+B) = \underset{V \subseteq \mathbb{F}^m,dimV=m-i-j}{min} \ \ \underset{v \in V,\Vert v \Vert = 1}{max}  \Vert (A+B)v \Vert \tag{1}\label{1}
$

Let $V_1,V_2 \subseteq \mathbb{F}^m,\ dimV_1=m-i,\ dimV_2=m-j$ are chosen so that $$\underset{v \in V_1,\Vert v \Vert = 1}{max}\Vert Av \Vert=\sigma_{i+1}(A)\ and\ \underset{v \in V_2,\Vert v \Vert = 1}{max}\Vert Bv \Vert=\sigma_{j+1}(B)$$ This is possible again due to the min-max theorem.

Now, let $W = V_1 \cap V_2$
$$
\begin{align}
\underset{v \in W, \Vert v \Vert = 1}{max} \Vert (A+B)v \Vert 
&\leqslant \underset{v \in W, \Vert v \Vert = 1}{max} 
\left(\Vert Av \Vert + \Vert Bv \Vert \right) \\
&\leqslant \underset{v \in W, \Vert v \Vert = 1}{max} 
\Vert Av \Vert + \underset{v \in W, \Vert v \Vert = 1}{max} 
\Vert Bv \Vert \\
&\leqslant \underset{v \in V_1, \Vert v \Vert = 1}{max} 
\Vert Av \Vert + \underset{v \in V_2, \Vert v \Vert = 1}{max} 
\Vert Bv \Vert \\
&=\sigma_{i+1}(A) + \sigma_{j+1}(B) \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
$$

Note that $dimW \geqslant m-i-j$, and by restrictig the choice of $v$ in $(\ref{2})$ to a subset $V \subseteq W$ with $dimV=m-i-j$, we can write 
$$
\underset{v \in V, \Vert v \Vert = 1}{max} \Vert (A+B)v \Vert \leqslant \sigma_{i+1}(A) + \sigma_{j+1}(B)
$$

We have proved the upper-bound for some example of $V \in \mathbb{F}^m, dimV=m-i-j$, so clearly this holds for the minimum over all $V$, *i.e.* we can write
$$
\underset{V \subseteq \mathbb{F}^m,dimV=m-i-j}{min} \ \ \underset{v \in V,\Vert v \Vert = 1}{max}  \Vert (A+B)v \Vert \leqslant \sigma_{i+1}(A) + \sigma_{j+1}(B)\\
\implies \sigma_{i+j+1}(A+B) \leqslant \sigma_{i+1}(A) + \sigma_{j+1}(B)\ [using\ (\ref{1})]
$$
Writing $i=i-1$ and $j=j-1$, we get the desired result.